# Handling large amounts of 2 dimensional data

Tags: .net, storage

I hope you can help me with this one.
I am currently redesigning an application (.NET) and now I have come to the part were I 
have to overthink the data storage.

Basically every 10 seconds or so (can vary, but this is the fastest) I get a new dataset containing an array of float values and a timeStamp. (These arrays can be pretty large, so I have to deal with lots of data [Can go up to hundreds of mb or even gb]) The length of a array is fixed per procedure (lets call it run) but will vary during different runs. I will only look at one run at a time.

So my question is:

How do I save this data and how do I handle it in my application?

Especially if I want to read out a dataset with a specific timestamp,

a list of float values from a given index

and a 2d list of float values given an index range and a timestamp range.

[Edit: Data needs to be stored local]

Answer (score 0):

Azure Table Storage ...........

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I should have added that the data needs to be stored local.

Comment: Even free SQL express goes to 10 GB http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a database.

```
Run(int Id, datetime Timestamp) - PK: Id
Entry(int RunId, int Index, float Value) - PK: RunId, Index
```

Then, you can

```
SELECT Index, Value 
FROM Entry E 
    INNER JOIN Run R 
        ON E.RunId = R.Id
WHERE R.Timestamp = '00-00-00 00:00:00'
```

And

```
SELECT RunId, Value 
FROM Entry 
WHERE Index = 0
```

And

```
SELECT Timestamp, Index, Value 
FROM Entry E 
    INNER JOIN Run R 
        ON E.RunId = R.Id
WHERE 
    R.Timestamp <= '00-00-00 00:00:00' AND 
    R.Timestamp >= '00-00-00 00:00:00' AND
    E.Index <= 0 AND
    E.Index >= 0
```

Replacing 0 and '00-00-00 00:00:00' with appropriate data.

Comment: And make sure that you put all the right constraints, such as a foreign key constraint from Entry.RunId to Run.Id, and an identity on Run.Id